# When attempting to automatically move comments to chat, an error message appeared containing the string "null"

Tags: bug, comments, chat, error-message

I was commenting on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62165226/class-not-found-in-php-laravel-6-x-when-another-class-extends/62166630?noredirect=1#comment109983116_62166630) and the message appeared to move it to chat.

I clicked on it and received `null` [image: Error screenshot]

I've searched SO but couldn't find anything helpful. And after reloading the page I was not able to reproduce the error.

I'm on MacOS 10.15.4 using Firefox 76.0.1 (64-bit).